# Are females given official priesthood in any christian denomination?

Tags: priesthood, priests, female-clergy

My friend in UK claims to have gone to a church where the priest is a woman.
Are females given official priesthood in any christian denomination?

Comment: Too many to outline effectively in the Stack Exchange Q&A format. You might like to start with [Wikipedia's overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordination_of_women#Christianity).

Comment: This question shows a lack of research, to say the least.

Comment: The Church of England, the official (and largest) church in the UK has women priests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in "any Christian denomination" in the U.K.  Only in some Christian denominations.  For example:

Anglican Church (Church of England) who have female priests and bishops

Church of Scotland

Episcopal Church

> The first woman to be ordained as a minister in the Church of Scotland was the Revd Catherine McConnachie by the Presbytery of Aberdeen in 1969.  (Sources below)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordination_of_women_in_the_Church_of_Scotland
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordination_of_women_in_the_Anglican_Communion
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordination_of_women_in_the_Anglican_Communion#Scottish_Episcopal_Church

However, there are many U.K. Christian denominations who do not ordain women to the priesthood, or even to any role where they have authority over men.